# Database Structure for a leaderboard with trends

Tags: sql, mysql, database, data-structures, game-development

I am developing a game like app with an leaderboard and want the leaderboard to have this features:

- Show Top 100
- Show Top 100 Monthly, Weekly, Daily
- Show Trends next to every User (if the user moved up on the leaderboard show green up arrow, and if down then red down arrow)

Currently I have two tables:

**user:**

besides all userspecific data the table also has a points column

Query to get alltime TOP 100:

```
SELECT uuid, points FROM user ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 100
```

**user_scores:**

COLUMNS: id, uuid, user_uuid, game_uuid, score_change, timestamp

Here a few Pseudo Example Rows:

```
|id|    uuid   |    user_uuid   |   game_uuid    | score_change|ts|
|--|-----------|----------------|----------------|-------------|--|
|1 | some_uuid | uuid_of_user_a | uuid_of_game_a |      2      |22|
|2 | some_uuid | uuid_of_user_a | uuid_of_game_b |      1      |24|
|3 | some_uuid | uuid_of_user_a | uuid_of_game_c |      3      |28|
```

after every game the score change of a user gets written into here.

Query to get e.g. the weekly leaderboard:

```
SELECT SUM(score_change) AS total, user_uuid 
FROM user_scores WHERE timestamp > week_begin & timestamp < week_end
GROUP BY user_uuid ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 100
```

Of course i could also query the alltime TOP 100 out of the user_scores table, but i thought this is probably more efficient, because i don't have to fetch through the whole user_scores table.

So far so good. But how do implement the trends of the ranks?

Comment: RDBMS aren't an appropriate tool for doing time-series analysis (e.g. _trends_), consider using a time-series processor like Kafka.

Comment: Would you please share some rows of user_scores for a particular user???

Comment: I edited the question with example data

Answer (score 0):

Using CTE's and Window functions should be able to give you the output you're looking for.

Try the following code below:

**Current rankings and Previous rankings**

```
WITH current_rankings AS (
    SELECT 
        user_uuid, 
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(score_change) DESC) AS current_rank
    FROM 
        user_scores
    WHERE 
        timestamp >= this_week_start AND timestamp < this_week_end
    GROUP BY 
        user_uuid
    LIMIT 100
),
previous_rankings AS (
    SELECT 
        user_uuid, 
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(score_change) DESC) AS previous_rank
    FROM 
        user_scores
    WHERE 
        timestamp >= last_week_start AND timestamp < last_week_end
    GROUP BY 
        user_uuid
    LIMIT 100
)
```

**Combine to determine trends**

```
SELECT 
    c.user_uuid,
    c.current_rank,
    p.previous_rank,
    CASE 
        WHEN c.current_rank < p.previous_rank THEN 'up'
        WHEN c.current_rank > p.previous_rank THEN 'down'
        ELSE 'same'
    END AS trend
FROM 
    current_rankings c
LEFT JOIN 
    previous_rankings p ON c.user_uuid = p.user_uuid;
```

**NOTE**
Adjust `this_week_start`, `this_week_end`, `last_week_start`, and `last_week_end` to your timestamp calculation logic

Comment: Then obviously you can use the new  trend column to display the green or red flag on the frontend

Answer (score 0):

You can left-join the previous week's result, each set row-numbered by the `total`, and then subtract the row-numbers from each other to get the trend.

You need to think about what tyep of ranking you want: `ROW_NUMBER` `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`.

```
SELECT
  this.total,
  this.user_uuid,
  this.rn AS current_position,
  this.rn - prev.rn AS trend
FROM (
    SELECT
      SUM(us.score_change) AS total,
      us.user_uuid,
      RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(us.score_change) DESC) AS rn
    FROM user_scores us
    WHERE us.timestamp >= week_begin
      AND us.timestamp < week_end
    GROUP BY
      us.user_uuid
    ORDER BY
      total DESC
    LIMIT 100
) this
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      SUM(us.score_change) AS total,
      us.user_uuid,
      RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(us.score_change) DESC) AS rn
    FROM user_scores us
    WHERE us.timestamp >= prev_week_begin
      AND us.timestamp < week_begin
    GROUP BY
      us.user_uuid
    ORDER BY
      total DESC
    LIMIT 100  -- remove LIMIT to include trend for users who were > 100 previously
) prev ON prev.user_uuid = this.user_uuid;
```

You are right that filtering by `timestamp` will improve performance, but you would need proper indexing, something like `(timestamp, user_uuid) INCLUDE (score_change)`.